# How can I replace the <opt> tag in XML::Simple with the original tag name?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple) to edit an XML file. After which the updated data is sent to a new XML file. But this procedure produces `<opt></opt>` tag to be added and the original parent tag is lost. I want to replace `<opt>` with the original tag name. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stretching the limits of [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple). When you get to the point where you don't like exactly what it does, it's time for something else. What that something else is depends on your problem, but I like [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig).

Comment: You can get these sorts of things done with XML::Simple, but my advice stands: unless it does exactly what you want without you having to do anything, move on to something else.

Answer (score 2):

See [KeepRoot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple#KeepRoot_=%3E_1_#_in+out_-_handy). You should also consider enabling [strict mode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple#STRICT_MODE).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = XMLin(\*DATA, KeepRoot => 1, ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => ['the']);

print XMLout($x, KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => ['the']);

__DATA__
<this>
<that the="other">This that and the other</that>
</this>
```

Output:

```
<this>
  <that the="other">This that and the other</that>
</this>
```

Comment: The <opt> tag has now encapsulates the original root node.Is there a way to complete remove the <opt> tag?

Answer (score 0):

in the new xml file you can use regular experessions to find the pattern you want to remove and then replace with the pattern you want,that is original tag.

```
 @ar="xml file";
 $pat="tag you want to replace";
 $rep="original tag";


 foreach $a (@ar) {
   if ($a =~ s|$pat|$rep|gi;
   }
```

xml file hander name=@arr;